# URL validation using regex and Javascript for React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, regex-group

I am having below url for validation,

```
https://jira.company.com/browse/TICKET-12345
```

What i need is entered URL should be exactly like above mentioned and only number after  - can change, like ,

**https://jira.company.com/browse/TICKET-12345** or
**https://jira.company.com/browse/TICKET-9854**

I am using following regex,

```
      /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
```

but its not working..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you end up with this regex? It seems way overcomplicated for what you need.

Comment: Why not just getting the number after `TICKET` ?

Comment: I know its overcomplicated thats why I am looking for help..and added url should be same format as mentioned above

Comment: Are you looking for this: `https://jira\.company\.com/browse/TICKET-\d+` ?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried looks very complicated and has not really anything specifically to do with the jira url that you want to match.

If you are using JavaScript,escape the slashes and use the anchors:

```
^https:\/\/jira\.company\.com\/browse\/TICKET-\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZWKac/1).